Dynamically load a components angular?
In angular 18, i have a folder called typeForm where my components are stored. Each component has a different view, and I want each path to correspond to a component dynamically, something like:
// app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormComponent } from './form/form.component';
import { authGuard } from '../app/auth.guard';

import * as allComponents from './typeForm/*';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/form', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'form', component: FormComponent, canActivate: [authGuard] }
 
];


async function loadDynamicRoutes() {

  for (const key of allComponents) {
   
        routes.push({
          path: allComponents.componentName,
          component: allComponents.componentType,
          canActivate: [authGuard]
        });
      }
    }
loadDynamicRoutes();
  

Clearly, the code is wrong, but I don't know how I could do it or what alternative there is where I don't have to make a bunch of path declarations and a bunch of imports.

You can create a configuration object, that contains the path and the component import. This can be looped to get the desired result.
export const routes = [
    {
        path: 'a',
        component: AComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'b',
        component: BComponent,
    },
    ...
];

async function loadDynamicRoutes() {

  for (const element of routes) {
   
        routes.push({
          path: element.path,
          component: element.component,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        });
      }
    }
}

loadDynamicRoutes();

If you want something more dynamic, like for an API call, refer this answer.
Create dynamic paths in my routing - Angular / PrimeNg version

Do you know a way to map a folder and, with the obtained paths, dynamically import the components?

@JhormanTraslaviña Sounds complicated, but you can do it with node.js, angular wont be right for this, basically run a node.js script that creates a file, with this same object structure as my answer. Then angular code will use this structure to construct the routes. You can run it like node folderConverter.js && npm run start
